# How can user change the jre parameter values after the exe is generated in Launch4j?

Tags: java, installation, launch4j, launcher

Is it possible to change the jre parameter values after the exe file is generated through Launch4j?

The ideal scenario is like this:

The default parameter values are applied when the program is started. However, when the user wants to change some jre parameter values, he goes to a .ini file, MyProgram.ini for example, changes the values there, and the new values will be applied next time the program is started. I think eclipse uses the same way for its memory and some other parameter settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [documented](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Additional_jvm_options) on the launch4j page.

Comment: Yes, launch4j now supports a .ini file.